# df.append seems to clear the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am having trouble appending a series to a dataframe.  Here is my code:

```
for name in df['name'].unique():
    table_df = pd.DataFrame()
    series = pd.Series()
    for time_span in time_spans:
        series[time_span] = pd.Series([1,2,3,4])
        series.name = name
    table_df = table_df.append(series)
```

but when I look at table_df, it only contains the most recently appended series, with index as series.name (as desired) and columns of 'time_spans'.

Any help is appreciated, let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the dataframe outside the loop.

Try this:

```
table_df = pd.DataFrame()

for name in df['name'].unique():
    series = pd.Series()
    for time_span in time_spans:
        series[time_span] = pd.Series([1,2,3,4])
        series.name = name
    table_df = table_df.append(series)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I've been looking for that green checkmark for 3 or 4 questions, I'm still just under having enough reputation for my upvote to show up.